# Could there be a bug in `pandas.rolling.std` when custom weights are used?

Tags: python, pandas

I have observed odd behavior of `pandas.rolling.std` when custom weights are used and trying to understand what is happening. My question is about how this method works and if there could be a bug when custom weights are used, but below there is a visual example of what looks very suspicious.

Through [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.std.html) I get to the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/37ea63d540fd27274cad6585082c91b1283f963d/pandas/core/window/rolling.py#L2204-L2216) which immediately sends me to [this block](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.0.1/pandas/core/window/rolling.py#L1530-L1552). If I am not mistaken, at this the calculation of rolling variance goes into [this method](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/37ea63d540fd27274cad6585082c91b1283f963d/pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.pyx#L415-L476) implemented in a language (?) I am not familiar with... It is very likely I am missing something, but I do not see where weights are passed. Could this be an issue or could there be something else that is off?

### Example of suspicious behavior

Here is an example of a fictitious time series with an artificially introduced large to create a spike of the rolling estimator. In addition, I compute the estimator using `pandas.rolling.mean` which actually looks more sensible.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.Series(np.random.normal(size=500))
df.loc[125] = 15

# Calculation as I thought it is supposed to work
df_std_stock = (
    df.rolling(window=200, min_periods=100, win_type='exponential')
      .std(tau=-(25 / np.log(2)), center=0, sym=False)
)

# Calculation that produces results that look more sensible visually
df_std_custom = (
    (df ** 2).rolling(window=200, min_periods=100, win_type='exponential')
             .mean(tau=-(25 / np.log(2)), center=0, sym=False)
)
df_std_custom_mean = (
    df.rolling(window=200, min_periods=100, win_type='exponential')
       .mean(tau=-(25 / np.log(2)), center=0, sym=False)
)
df_std_custom = df_std_custom - df_std_custom_mean**2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely a bug. [An issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/53273) was filed and [a PR](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/55153) was proposed with more details explaining the issue.